# KML layer with 4000+ points ok from USA, cant show from Asia

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

i have a Google Map API v3 map that shows a kml layer added via
capacust= new google.maps.KmlLayer('MyURL....php?param=99',{preserveViewport:true});

It can be seen ok from USA, Latin America, but says users in Asia (Thailand) the points are not show, this are waipoints aprox, 4000.

Showing smaller amount (2000 or less) it are shown, is there a way to tell the map to "wait" for the kml? the kml is generated from PHP

What can be the issue with this, the server is in USA and works ok from users in America (Latin and North America)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KmlLayer rendering is time sensitive.  If the PHP process that generates the kml is not generating it quickly enough, it is possible that distance may matter.  I'm not sure what you are generating on the fly, perhaps you can investigate FusionTables or a faster server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it are customers points, up to 4000 points. The data comes from a MySQL database via php I construct a kml that is the one overlayer from js on the Maps API